# Multidrop one or two lane bus

Tags: serial, rs232, rs485, bus, rs422

I like to design a single master, several slave (up to 100) application and looking for a reliable (up to 30meter) multi drop bus. One or two lane is preferred, I will use daisy chain topology therefore USB is not suitable and also it is an overkill.

My data rate is low and intermittent, once every 3-5 sec and probably <10KB. The slaves are not synchronized.

I thought about using RS232 and implement an algo where slave transmits if there is no traffic. (Similar to Ethernet). I prefer something a bit more robust.

Also, current thinking is to wake all slaves when master transmit where all slaves receive the message, they all parse it but the one we targeted takes action. Not very efficient but it would work.

Comment: RS422 related maybe. Certainly not RS232

Comment: Most of the suggestions below (so far) are based on use of RS422 differential signalling in various ways and/or protocols that build on top of it. If you want to "roll your own" you'll find RS422 an excellent place to start looking. Hardware is available and well priced and performance under various loadings and distances is well described in the literature.

Comment: RS422 or 485 are nice but not enough for up to 100 nodes, I have to insert several bridge points to achieve high number of nodes. Could these be hacked for more nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the suggestions so far  are based on use of RS422 differential signalling as per my original comment, used  in various ways and/or protocols that build on top of it. If you want to "roll your own" you'll find RS422 an excellent place to start looking. Hardware is available and well priced and performance under various loadings and distances is well described in the literature.

RS422  - [Pandoras box]( all link to web  pages)
RS422 multidrop [as above](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=rs422&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=kMJBT7fiCK-5iAekk9HaBA&ved=0CEgQsAQ&biw=1333&bih=750#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=rs422+multidrop&pbx=1&oq=rs422+multidrop&aq=f&aqi=g-S2&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=127720l130884l0l131468l10l10l0l6l6l0l317l1171l2-2.2l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=92bbe18d5867d01d&biw=1333&bih=720)

[QUICK REFERENCE FOR RS485, RS422, RS232 AND RS423](http://www.rs485.com/rs485spec.html)

[Wikipedia RS422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422)

Maxim tutorial 723[Selecting and Using RS-232, RS-422, and RS-485 Serial Data Standards](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/723)

TI RS422 products page - very valuable - even if you don't use their ICs ultimately 

[Cross Reference - Application Notes - Training - Tools & Software - Block Diagrams
Analog eLAB ™](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=544&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T)

They say

- Texas Instruments is the world leader in RS-422, with a selection of transceivers for any application. TI provides industry-standard RS-422 solutions for industrial automation, motion control, e-meters, security electronics, building automation and hundreds of other applications where robust communication with high noise-immunity is needed over long cable lengths. TI offers RS-422 with multiple drivers/receivers in a single package and multiple temperature ranges.

[RS485.COM](http://www.rs485.com) -  Commercial page but VERY useful

[Their FAQ](http://www.rs485.com/pfaq.html)

[RS485 links](http://www.rs485.com/plinks.html)

---

[NatSemi RS485 application notes](http://www.national.com/apnotes/RS-485.html)

NatSemi[RS485 overview](http://www.bb-elec.com/tech_articles/rs422_485_app_note/overview.asp)

**Other:**

[Basic 422 intro](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-422.html)

Answer (score 1):

The standard serial multidrop busses are [RS-422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422), [RS-423](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-423), and [RS-485](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485).  I'm not sure if these are what you want, but it is certainly a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

One popular bus in the automobile and industrial fields is [CAN Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). It is also being used in the marine industry where it is implemented as part of [NMEA 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000).

A related standard is [LIN bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network), which is often used with CAN and is a slower and cheaper sub-network.

There is also a super version of CAN with dual backbones for redundancy being used by BMW and others (sorry, can't remember the name of that version).

All three of these buses inter-operate and have wide support from major semiconductor manufacturers. Since this is designed for safety systems in automobiles, chips are cheap and available in extended temperature ranges. Many microcontrollers have CAN on-board.

Here is a TI whitepaper, [Introduction to the Controller Area Network (CAN)](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa101a/sloa101a.pdf)

Comment: I think you mean FlexRay with "super version of CAN".

Answer (score 0):

Thought I may contribute the solution I found. 
(*may aswell document it somewhere xD*)

I recently had to interface to two RS232 "slaves" connected to a single RS232 "master" which always iniciates communication and slaves which are adressed respond.

Since RS232 is intended for point to point, I initially was going to convert to RS485 and create a bus in RS485 and then convert back to RS232 but didn't have enough converters on hand so came up with the following circuit.

After a bit of testing I found out that the Rx pin of a typical USB to RS232 seems to have a 10k "pull-up" to GND which causes a voltage drop to be seen when the master should see a negative voltage. The resistances are designed to minimize the voltage drop while limiting the current to 15 mA between any two slave in worst case scenario (+25 --> -25V) --> 50V/3k3 ~ 15mA.
I also used Diodes 1N4448 instead of 1N4148 which is in the schematic because I had them on hand and they have a lower voltage drop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2I8RI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is extensible to many more, but you will probably need to play with the resistance value depending on what the available sourceing current your slaves have.. and also depending on the master, each slave will also and onto into TXout pin some load.

Maybe this may help someone else in the future.